# Links inside email are displayed as double plain text

Tags: email, html-email

In our web shop we email customers after each purchase. Up until now all emails displayed properly, but now, in some cases all links inside the email is displayed as doubled plain text. This is happening only to some customers, and I can not find anything about that issue and how to solve it.

**Correct Display:**

[image]

**Incorrect Display:**

[image]

**NOTE 1:**

I created HTML for that email. The link is wrapped with `<a>` tag, but when we inspect the incorrectly displayed email, the `<a>` is removed and only the text is present in the DOM.

**NOTE 2:**

This is only happening to some customers. We checked and they don't have any ad blocked enabled. Also, this is not browser related issue since they also tried to open email on different browsers.

Comment: There is nothing generally in email that would do such a thing. The issue lies in the software that sends your email. Unless you wrote the code that sends the email, this is not a stackoverflow appropriate question; you likely need to contact support of whatever vendor you are using.

Comment: I created HTML for the email. Let me add that the question.

Comment: Let me repeat and somewhat rephrase. Email clients support HTML. There is nothing specifically about email or email standards that would turn your HTML in that specific text format. *something* adds brackets and strips HTML, and it's not email clients itself. If you didn't write the email software, talk to whoever did.

Comment: I might be able to help identify the symptom if you share the full multipart email source. It's possible that the email client with this issue prefers the text version over the html version, but even if we identify what's going wrong, if you didn't write the software the sends email, you can't fix this bug.

Comment: I see. I will check that. Thank you.

Comment: Is this plain text content in an HTML email or text in a plain text version of your HTML email? Your title is a little confusing as there are two different types of formatting for email  - https://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/email-marketing/html-vs-plain-text-emails-everything-you-need-to-know/#:~:text=types%20of%20information.-,HTML%20emails%20have%20everything%20plain%20text%20emails%20don't%20have,a%20more%20visually%20engaging%20experience.

Comment: It is a link in email's HTML. Yeah, let me change a title a little.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens with Outlook.com and Outlook 365 environments. If the link does not have a http:// or https:// (or other) protocol, it will do this.

Therefore, ensure all your links use a protocol, i.e. `<a href="https://www.link.com">...</a>`, and NOT `<a href="www.link.com">...</a>`

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anyone else winds up here ... we had a similar issue

Our HTML bulk-email (sent programmatically via Exchange) showed formatted correctly in SENT ITEMS, but arrived (when viewed in Outlook) somewhat broken. It was fine if we emailed to e.g. GMail / Hotmail, so probably only a problem with Outlook rendering.

The Outlook presentation was PLAIN TEXT and not Rich / HTML. Noticeable because "View Source" was greyed out. (The content, as sent, definitely had HTML / HEEAD / BODY etc. tags, and it validated OK at W3C - Outlook removed all such HTML tags - seems strange that Outlook decided to display in plain text and then remove all the, correctly coded, HTML tags)

Some, but NOT all, `<a href="xxx">yyy</a>` tags displayed wrongly - in particular the tag `<a href="https://www.example.com/">https://www.example.com/</a>` was what we, eventually, found had caused the email to render (in Outlook) as plain text - all HTML tags stripped and some LINKs rendered wrongly.  That HTTPS link did render correctly, but others in the same email which were coded as `<a href="https://www.link.com/MyPath">www.link.com/MyPath</a>` rendered as

```
www.link.com/MyPath<https://www.link.com/MyPath>
```

same with `mailto:` links

Removing the `HTTPS://` from within the `<a href...>HTTPS://xxx</a>` tag fixed the problem - took us a while to find though!

So basically it seems that the `HREF` property should include `https://` and the value within the `<a>` tag should NOT